How to assign an integer to a 3 byte ndarray?
I have (W)RGB color data as integers, and I'd like to store it in a numpy ndarray of uint8.
If I have a WRGB color, I can assign the int value to a view of the array:
array = np.zeros((3,4),dtype=np.uint8)
wrgb = array[:,::-1]
col = array.view(dtype=np.uing32)

col[0]=0xff1001 # equals wrgb[0][1:] = [255,16,1]
col[1]=0x01020304 # equals wrgb[1] = [1,2,3,4]

But if I have a pure RGB value and want to leave the white/alpha channel untouched, I can't assign to a view of a slice, since views require "matching" array sizes (np.array([1,2,3],dtype=np.uint8).view(dtype=np.uint32) throws an error).
Is there any elegant way to do an in-place assignment like that, or would I have to assign the "uint24"-color to a temporary 4 byte array, and then copy just the 3 bytes I'm interested in to the final array?

What is the int value you want to assign to RGB? How is it given? Is it guaranteed to be no more than 24 bits?

Maybe array[:] = np.array([0xff1001]).view(np.uint8)[:3]?

In general, the int values are used in other parts of the software; either passed from/to other functions, or given as hexadecimal strings (at most 6 characters, converted with int(x,16)). In this specific case, it's safe to assume that the values are smaller than 0x1000000 (and non-negative), though python ints are internally always at least 32 bits.

array[:] = np.array([0xff1001]).view(np.uint8)[:3] would work, but by constructing another array and then copying the interesting values - I was looking/hoping for a more elegant solution. Otherwise, a col[i]=col[i]&0xFF000000 + 0xff1001 might be easier/more elegant/perhaps even more efficient... (or =col[i]&0xFF000000 + newvalue&0xFFFFFF if explicitly discarding the upper bits)

Though my bitwise and approach would not easily allow assigning integer values to passed RGB-only slices of the WRGB array...

Using view for operating on RGB values is not portable. It implicitly assume a given endianness which can change from one platform to another and even at runtime on some CPUs (eg. ARM). If you use view once, then you should always read/write values using that. Thus, you cannot assume 0xFF000000 means the first component (typically R) is 0xFF. If the order matters, then you must either check the endianness (to avoid bugs on other machines), or use uint8 values instead (possibly with reshape for convenience).

For portable packing unpacking, you can use the standard struct CPython package. An alternative solution is just to do bit manip yourself with basic shift and logical and/or. The former is faster for few values and the later is faster for large arrays (thanks to vectorization). Both are very slow in the respective other case.

@JérômeRichard Actually, in my case, it's guaranteed that 0xFF000000 means the "white" channel is set to 0xFF and so on; the uint8-view is the part that requires endianness checks for portability.
Under which circumstances can endianness change at runtime?

@sh4dow AFAIK, on ARM, there is an instruction setend which can be used to switch the mode from BE to LE or from LE to BE. Instructions like LDR or STR are bi-endian (little endian by default). A C compiler can possibly freely use such an instruction (IDK for an OS). This means you cannot assume a load translated to a LDR is always LE or always BE. I expect Numpy developers not to care about this so the compiler should behave in a default way and certainly generate just LDR/STR instructions (I do not expect it to generate any setend by default but who know...).

@sh4dow C libraries might change it (in a temporarry way or not). I expect the libc to setup it at startup based on the OS configuration. Also please note that the endianness is not the only problem technically if you read/write data with a different granularity (eg. 8-bit vs 32-bits) : the strict aliasing rule also applies. Whether this is a problem in the Numpy code is arguable. In practice, this should be fine as long as Numpy functions are never inlined (which is never the case for CPython calls so far). See this related post.
